Why is a weightlifting bar easier to slide while rotating it?
Imagine a bench press setup. The bar might be off center in the stand, so you want to correct it.
This is much easier to do, if you rotate the bar while sliding it. What is the explanation to this? I mean, the rotation is completely orthogonal to the rotating plane.

Why does twisting a cork make it easier to remove from a bottle?

@mmesser314 Don't think that's the same. You don't get rolling motion when twisting a cork, since it has contact all around it.

Is it easier to drag a car when it is Parked, or when it is in Neutral gear with the wheels rolling?

What do you mean by the bar being off center.

@RC_23 I have never tried to drag a car sideways. Have you?

Voting to reopen. This is a different case than the cork. The cork starts sliding, which means you are fighting dynamic friction instead of static friction. And you have the handles of the corkscrew to help you overcome static friction. Here the bar rolls, which makes it easier to slide parallel to the axis.

I believe the answer is while rotating the bar, the friction is dynamic, but to slide the bar from a standstill, you need to overcome the static friction also. That is my guess, might be wrong.

Isn't it the combination of these answers: @mmesser314's insight that starting the rotation is easier because the bar can roll, then turning that into a corkscrew motion, then CPlus's point that dynamic friction is easier than static? My reframing of the question: once the bar is rotating, (how) does that make the longitudinal friction easier to overcome? Is there less static friction for a wheel that is rolling because it has had less time to form bonds with the surface?

This question took a while to visualise. You should have included a picture or something so that we could have avoided the arguments in the comments. This question might come down to body mechanics; our muscles, having derived from ape muscles for hanging on branches, may well have stronger rotational capabilities than sliding. Once the rotation is setup, the bar would be having kinetic friction and not static friction, leading to easier sliding. That is nothing to do with less time to form bonds. Friction is rather interesting; in motion, the surface is at a few thousand degrees Kelvin.

@BobD I'm really sorry, but I don't know how to explain it if you don't understand. To me it's fairly obvious. Off center means that it is not centered.

@klutt like naturallyinconsistent said a diagram or picture would help

@BobD https://share.sketchpad.app/24/704-b392-a285db.jpeg

@klutt thanks for the sketch. I don’t understand why it would be necessary to slide and rotate the bar. Why not simply lift it off the rack and reposition it?

@BobD Because it's heavy.

@klutt Well, yeah. But you’re lifting it anyway, aren’t you? That’s why they call it weightlifting
